# how to process all records in CTE

Tags: for-loop, common-table-expression

I am trying to first combining multiple companies based on email and then  break table column in multiple columns (because of data limit in other tool where this column will be used) with certain length which is working fine in my logic . The only issue is , this is working for only 1 rows . How can I process all rows of CTE . I was reading recursive cte but I don't think recrusvie cte apply in my scenerio. is it wrong idea to use CTE in this kind of scenerio ? or is there any way I can process all rows of cte ?

Below is my code which is working for single rows but not all the rows .

CREATE PROCEDURE [Add_NewSP] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
AS 
    DECLARE @255Chars       VARCHAR(max) 
           ,@removableChar  INTEGER
           ,@remianigString VARCHAR(max)
           ,@Company1       VARCHAR(max) 
           ,@Company2       VARCHAR(max)
           ,@Company3       VARCHAR(max) 
           ,@Company4       VARCHAR(max)
           ,@Company5       VARCHAR(max) 
           ,@Company6       VARCHAR(max)
           ,@Company7       VARCHAR(max)
           ,@Company8       INTEGER 
           ,@remainigChar   VARCHAR(max) 
           ,@email  varchar(max)
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

BEGIN 
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
      --Begin  -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
      SET nocount ON;

```
    ;WITH contact_cte 
       AS (SELECT  
                  company, 
                  email, 

           FROM   [Table1] a 
                  INNER JOIN TableB b 
                          ON b.id = a.type_id 
                  ), 

 contact_cte_ext 
       AS (SELECT 
                  company, 
                  email, 
                  Stuff((SELECT ',' + company 
                         FROM   contact_cte AS t1 
                         WHERE  t1.email = t2.email 
                         FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') campaign_company, 
                  Stuff((SELECT ',' + account 
                         FROM   contact_cte AS t1 
                         WHERE  t1.email = t2.email 
                         FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') campaign_account 
           FROM   contact_cte AS t2) 



  SELECT @remianigString = campaign_company , @email= contact_email  FROM  contact_cte_ext 


  DECLARE @cntvar VARCHAR(10), @company VARCHAR(255) , @newCompany VARCHAR(max) = '' , @sqlCommand varchar(max)

  WHILE Len(@remianigString) > 0 

    BEGIN 

        SET @255Chars = LEFT(@remianigString, 255); 
            if(Len(@remianigString) > 255)
              Begin
                 SET @removableChar = Charindex(',', Reverse(@255Chars)) - 1 
                 PRINT '@removableChar length' +  Convert(varchar(10),  @removableChar);
              END ;
            ELSE 
              BEGIN
             SET @removableChar = -1 ;
              PRINT '@removableChar length' +  Convert(varchar(10),  @removableChar);
             END ;


        SET @company = Substring(@255Chars, 0, (Len(@255Chars) - @removableChar )); 
        SET @sqlCommand = 'Update table3  SET  company_' 
                          + Convert(varchar(10), @cnt)  
                          + '  =  '''   +  @company +   ''' ' 
                          +  'where contact_email = ''' +  @email 
                          + '''' ;
        PRINT @sqlCommand ;
        EXEC (@sqlCommand);


        print 'COMPANY' +  @company
            if(Len(@remianigString) > 255)
              Begin
                  SET @remianigString = Substring(@remianigString, Len(@company)+2,Len(@remianigString)-1); 
              END ;
            ELSE 
              BEGIN
                  SET @remianigString = Substring(@remianigString, Len(@company)+2,Len(@remianigString)); 
              END ;
       -- SET @remianigString = Substring(@remianigString, Len(@company)+2,Len(@remianigString)-1); 
        PRINT 'remoianingstring' +  @remianigString;
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1; 

     END;
```

END 
--EXEC Add_NEWSP

I want to process all rows in CTE . right now it's just processing 1st row in cte tabl .

Here is the data example 
[image]

Comment: Use a cursor to do that https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/

Comment: Does the cursor work with CTE ? I thought it's only for regular table or temp table ?

Comment: yes, it does but I just sat that you are using 2 CTE's and Stored procedure is messy. If you could provide some data samples and tell us exactly what you would like the output to be maybe I could help you clear it a bit.  What I understand from this SP is that you get some data from t1 and t2 and the according to that one you update t3. I am sure that there is a cleaner way to do it using maybe temp table and cursor than CTE and cursor

Comment: Thanks Claudio! Below is the screen shot for actual data and expected result . CTE table doing the Step1 and all that complex logic after CDC is trying to bring result in Expected Format . Please let me know if there is any better way to do it . I am planning to convert CDE to temp and cursor because so far I am not seeing any advantage of cde here .

Comment: I have added data sample in original questions . thanks!